# my copy and paste shortcuts do not work

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, copy

My copy (Ctrl + C) and paste (Ctrl + V) shortcuts are not working.  How do I fix them?

I suspect that I "broke" them somehow when I was making changes to input method or keyboard layout.

Anyway I need help resetting the shortcuts. I don't know any other method to copy and paste because right click does not do anything either.

Comment: what is your OS? how did you change input methods? did you edit any files?

Comment: I believe the Gnome Terminal default shortcuts are Shift+Ctrl+C and Shift+Crtl+V. Have a look at the Preferences to see and change them.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. My original shortcuts were Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V. I wanted to create shortcuts for special characters that I use while typing foreign languages. I opened input method and made sure that it was set to ibus.  Then I downloaded tweaks and set LCtrl as a compose key and created shortcuts for accent marks. This method did not give me all the special characters that I wanted.  So I deleted tweaks and added foreign language keyboards which include all the special characters. But LCtrl no longer works with copy, paste shortcuts and I can't figure out how to reset them.

Comment: So I re-installed Gnome Tweaks and disabled compose key and this restored copy, paste shortcuts with LCtrl.